# My flight to Vietnam leaves on the day before my visa starts, but arrives 5:30 on the starting date of my visa. Will I have problems boarding?

Tags: visas, vietnam, vietnam-airlines

I have a Vietnamese visa starting on the 30th of June.

My flight to Vietnam leaves on the 29th of June 23:10h, and arrives on Hanoi on the 30th of June 5:30h.

Is there a chance I might not be allowed to board my Vietnam Airlines flight, since the visa is not valid by the time I get into the plane?

Comment: Kinda, but having confirmation for Vietnam would help.

Comment: This is a universal thing, if that wasn't the case, many travels would be impeded by overnight flights like yours, the deciding factor is when you actually present at border control (which is a few minutes after deboarding usually)